# Unable to get the date value in d3

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, charts, multiline

I am trying to create a multiline chart in d3.

I have selected needed fields that I am interested in for the line chart and able to view the data just fine.

The issue is I am inable to get the date values form the data.

Below is my code :
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqX16.png)

When I checked on the console, I am getting undefined values.

Thanks,
Blyzz

Comment: Please paste here the code, or a contrived version of it - having to read from an image makes it difficult to follow and/or copypaste for others to try and answer

Comment: getting undefined for dates here :                                                                                                                     d3.dsv(",", "boardgame_ratings.csv", function (d) {
      return {
        // format data attributes if required
             "datert" : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date),
             "gameName1": d['Catan'],
             "gameName2" : d["Dominion=count"],
             
       
             
            
            
      };
    }).then(function (values){
     
           console.log(values.date)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the contents of boardgame_ratings.csv? Also, it is important to note that `values` is an array of objects, where each object represents a row from the CSV file. There is no `values.date` property, since `values` is an array.